# Java Runtime Kubuntu 18.04 LTS to get Blu-Ray Menu in VLC

Tags: java, vlc, blu-ray

as you might have guessed from the topic, I am searching for a way to get Blu-Ray Menus working in VLC. I am running on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit. In order to play Blu-Ray discs I installed MakeMKV and use its codec as an input for VLC. This works.

I have installed:

- VLC latest 64bit
- Oracle Java from linuxuprising which is supposed to be 64bit (according to the sources), it is set as default
- I removed all other JDKs and JREs

Still VLC tells me that no disc menus are available due to no java found.

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: I just checked it on Win10. Installed VLC 64bit, MakeMKV and Java 64bit, works straight away. So it must be something with the java installation on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install the Blu-ray Java module

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libbluray-bdj libbluray-bin
   ```
2. Restart VLC

Comment: That is the answer indeed! Thanks for that mate! One more thing, I can't use the mouse to navigate in the menu. Only Keyboard works. Is that normal?

Comment: Yay, Linux again. It is working on one machine, but not on the other. Does one of the libs conflict with other libbluray files?

Comment: Ah, got it. For some reason JAVA_HOME was set to a version that I un-installed. It was set in the profile.d so I had to edit the sh script there to get the JRE version 8 up and running. Now the menus work on the second machine as well.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install the Java 8 (a later version seems to be a problem) and Blu-ray Java module

```
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk libbluray-bdj libbluray-bin
```

2. Restart VLC