# VLC not seeing that java is installed

Tags: java, vlc, openjdk

Running Ubuntu 20.04
Java:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1ubuntu1-b09)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

ERROR:
Java required:
This Blu-ray disc requires Java for menus support.Java was not found on your system.
The disc will be played without menus.

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

It is like VLC is not even seeing that java is installed any help would appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install the Blu-ray Java module:

```
 sudo apt-get install libbluray-bdj libbluray-bin
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227803/389769)